# How to control an Iframes site with buttons and links?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe and i want to navigate through a list of external websites with some previous and next buttons however i wanted to have the links visible as well on a sidebar so when clicked it automatically goes to that site in the iframe.

I previously had tried some php with ajax and also just regular javascript/jquery with onclick events etc and thought this would be a fairly task easy however so far i have not been able to get this working correctly.

The current html for the page i need this on is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="resources/favicon.ico">

    <title>Site Browser</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
        body,html,.main-display-area,.col-md-10 {
            height:100%;
        }

        .myframe {
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            position:absolute;"
        }

        .frame-container {
            padding-left: 0px; 
            padding-top: 0px;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site Browser</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" id="navForm" method="post" action="/">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input value="< Previous" id="previous" class="btn btn-success btn-fixed" type="button">
                </div>
                &nbsp;
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input value="Next >" id="next" class="btn btn-success btn-fixed" type="button">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar sidebar-style">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar sidebar-scrollable">
            <li class="active"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bing.com/">Bing</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/">Google</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 frame-container">
        <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" id="myframe" class="myframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it Cross Domain ? If you load some xDomain windows in a iframe they won't take communication from the window opener.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're most of the way there. You're simply missing some targets on your hyperlinks:

```
<a href="http://www.bing.com/" target="myframe">Bing</a>
```

Comment: If i add these and click them they open a new tab in chrome browser rather than opening the website in the iframe on the page.

Answer (score 0):

At least two of the sites you're trying to display in a frame here (specifically, Google and Stack Overflow) use [the `X-Frame-Options` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to prevent them from being displayed in frames. This header cannot be overridden by your site — you will need to pick other sites to display, or find another way to present them.

Comment: Well it could be any sites, i just listed those as an example but i would have other sites yeah :D